# POST method not taking file inputs

Tags: php, file, post, methods

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is where we add Party.</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="viewParties.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

PartyList:<br>
<input type="text" name="partylist"><br>
<input type="file" name="pafile"><br><br>

President:<br>
<input type="text" name="president"><br>
<input type="file" name="pfile"><br><br>

Vice President:<br>
<input type="text" name="vicepresident"><br>
<input type="file" name="vpfile"><br><br>

Secretary:<br>
<input type="text" name="secretary"><br>
<input type="file" name="secpfile"><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit"><br><br>

</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Basically what I want to happen is for the POST Method to take both Names and File Locations. But when I print_r($_POST) in another PHP File, it only shows the Names. Does anybody know how to remedy this?

Comment: use print_r($_FILES);  for printing file values

Comment: write like this `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: mhmm. =) a tad late but thanks tho/ =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. Turns out I needed, not only to print($_POST) to see what I submitted but also, to print_r($_FILES) to see what files I submitted. I did some tinkering and this is what I found. Hope this helps someone else. =)